# Eager Loading Include use issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity

I am very new to MVC and Entity Framework and am trying to follow the asp.net tutorials and have run into a major snag. I have a table that displays correctly but shows the foreign key in the table instead of the data from the reference table. I think I am wanting to utilize eager loading here but I am not sure where to place my include. I believe the tutorial on asp.net is for an older version of MVC. I understand that my include should go in the following snippet. I am trying to include the artist type.

First, part of my model class:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<tblArtist>()
            .HasMany(e => e.tblArtisttblArtistType)
            .WithRequired(e => e.tblArtist)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<tblArtist>()
            .HasMany(e => e.tblIssueArtist)
            .WithRequired(e => e.tblArtist)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<tblArtist>()
            .HasMany(e => e.tblIssueAutograph)
            .WithRequired(e => e.tblArtist)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<tblArtistType>()
            .HasMany(e => e.tblArtisttblArtistType)
            .WithRequired(e => e.tblArtistType)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

And my controller code:

```
public class tblArtistsController : Controller
{
    private joerdieComicsModel1 db = new joerdieComicsModel1();

    // GET: tblArtists
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View(db.tblArtist.ToList());
    }

    // GET: tblArtists/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        tblArtist tblArtist = db.tblArtist.Find(id);
        if (tblArtist == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(tblArtist);
    }
```

I understand that the include code should go in the public ActionResult Index() method but I am lost as to how that is done.

Thank you.

Comment: What information/data you specifically want to eager load / display ?

Comment: artistType from tblArtistType along with the data that is being displayed now. Which is the data from the artist table.

Comment: How are Artist and ArtistTypes are connected ? Can you add the relevant part of these classes to the question.

Comment: I am happy to add more of my class into my question. But I think it's there. I could be wrong though. Artist and artistType are connected through tblArtisttblArtistType. That table has foreign keys to both the tblArtist and tblArtistType. Does that answer your question? Sorry if I am not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

When you have Many to Many relation Entity Framework 
automatically Create Table Interface but to relations that have foreign key
you model must "EX : ArtistId".

For Example :
           **Person.cs**

```
  public class Person
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
  }
```

**Book.cs**

```
    public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }
}
```

In Model Builder :

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
             HasMany(_ => _.Books)
            .WithRequired(_ => _.Person)
            .HasForeignKey(_ => _.PersonId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

And See :
          [One To Many](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Okay. I am starting to get it here. My model builder looks okay. And each of my classes, tblArtist amd tblArtistType now have public virtual ICollection<tblArtistType> artistTypes { get; set; } and "public virtual ICollection<tblArtist> artists { get; set; }" respectively. But on my index page, I attempted to use @Html.ListBox("artistTypes", new SelectList(item.artistTypes, "tblArtistTypeID", "ArtistType")) and am getting an invalid object error on 'dbo.tblArtistTypetblArtists' which doesn't exist anywhere in my build. My connecting table does have an ID of it's own. Could that be the problem?